# Excel Format NOW()

Tags: excel, openoffice-calc

I know nothing about Excel (technically I'm using "Calc" in Open Office).  I'm trying to set up a cell to auto-update with a date/time stamp if another cell has data entered into it with this code...

```
=IF(AND(D14<>"";D14<>0);format(NOW(), "mmm. dd, yyyy @ h:nn am/pm");"")
```

I want the date/time stamp to be like this: **Oct. 3, 2015 @ 10:30am**

When I try the code above I get "ERR: 508" in the cell.

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Found it.  Just formatting the cell to "MMM. DD, YYYY \@ H:MM AM/PM" gave me what I needed.